# Three.js - SELECTED SpotLight & dat.gui

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

I'm adding a SpotLight to my scene and an OctahedronGeometry (as helper) in order to make it visible to the user.
The user has to be able to move the SpotLight with the transformControls by clicking on it to select it. And it works !

But, when selected, I want to be able to edit the SpotLight settings. The problem is that I'm interacting with the geometry (which is selected) and not with the SpotLight directly.

Here's my function:

```
var aSpotLight = document.getElementById("addSpotLight");
aSpotLight.addEventListener("click", addSpotLight, false);

    function addSpotLight(){
        var object = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0, Math.PI * 0.1, 10 );
        object.name = 'SpotLight';
        var helper = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.OctahedronGeometry(10, 0), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ee00, wireframe: true, transparent: true } ));
        helper.position.set( 0, 30, 0 );
        object.position.set( 0, 30, 0 );

        scene.add(helper);
        helper.add( object );

        objects.push(object);

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        material.needsUpdate = true;
    }
```

And here's my dat.gui settings:

```
selectedObjectAppearance = {
        lightColor : 0xffffff,
        lightDistance : 10,
        lightIntensity : 1,
        lightlightShadowDarkness : 1
    };

    guiObject.addColor(selectedObjectAppearance, 'lightColor').name('Light Color').onChange(function (e) {SELECTED.children.color = new THREE.Color(e);});
        guiObject.add( selectedObjectAppearance, 'lightDistance' ).min(1).max(15).step(0.5).name('Light distance').onChange(function (e) {SELECTED.distance = e;});
        guiObject.add( selectedObjectAppearance, 'lightIntensity' ).min(0).max(1).step(0.05).name('Light intensity').onChange(function (e) {SELECTED.intensity = e;});
        guiObject.add( selectedObjectAppearance, 'lightlightShadowDarkness' ).min(0).max(1).step(0.05).name('Light shadow darkness').onChange(function (e) {SELECTED.shadowDarkness = e;});
```

**[EDIT]**
And here's my SELECTED variable:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(event.target).is('canvas')){
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
        if(intersects.length > 0){
            SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;

            control.attach(SELECTED);
            scene.add(control);
            $(guiObject.domElement).attr("hidden", false);
            // SELECTED.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
        } else{
            control.detach(SELECTED);
            scene.remove(control);
            control.update();
            $(guiObject.domElement).attr("hidden", true);
        }
    } else{
        $(guiObject.domElement).attr("hidden", false);
    }
}
```

How could it be done?

Comment: where does your `SELECTED` variable get its value from?

Comment: See above in the EDIT :)

Comment: you don't need `objects` variable! you can use `scene.children`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
guiObject.addColor(selectedObjectAppearance, 'lightColor').name('Light Color').onChange(function (e) {
    scene.traverse( function( child ) {
        var object = helper.children[0];

        if ((SELECTED === helper) && (child instanceof THREE.SpotLight)) {
            object.color = new THREE.Color(e);
        }
        else if ((SELECTED === helper) && (child instanceof THREE.PointLight)) {
            object.color = new THREE.Color(e);
        }
        else if ((SELECTED === helper) && (child instanceof THREE.DirectionalLight)) {
            object.color = new THREE.Color(e);
        }
    } );
});
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options and which one you follow depends on what you want to do.

One option is to add the `helper` as a child of your `object`. Then, when you select the helper, its parent is available to you to manipulate the values.

The second option is to add a name to the `helper` (i.e. `helper.name = SpotLightHelper`) and then do:

```
scene.traverse( function( child ) {
    if (child.name === 'SpotLightHelper') {
        // do what you want here
    }
    else if (child.name === 'PointLightHelper') {
        // do what you want here
    }
} );
```

Comment: You're right! It works! :P
And how would do you if you had SpotLight, PointLight and DirectionalLight to manage at the same time, in order to be able to edit the SELECTED object?

Comment: You control what `SELECTED` is and means.

Comment: What does it mean? :s

Comment: In regards to your question, I thought you wanted the variable `SELECTED` to be a `SpotLight` at one instance or a `PointLight` at another instance. So you would code according to the meaning of the variable.

Comment: I just have to be able to select a spotlight, or a pointlight whenever I want and then be able to edit its settings with dat.gui

Comment: Yes, give them appropriate names and let `scene.traverse()` do the job for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93373/discussion-between-srcbh-and-gaitat).

Answer (score -1):

I did

```
guiObject.addColor(selectedObjectAppearance, 'lightColor').name('Light Color').onChange(function (e) {
    scene.traverse( function( child ) {

        if (SELECTED.name === 'SpotLightHelper') {
            var object = scene.getObjectByName("SpotLight");
            object.color = new THREE.Color(e);
        }
        else if (SELECTED.name === 'PointLightHelper') {
            var object = scene.getObjectByName("PointLight");
            object.color = new THREE.Color(e);
        }
        else if (SELECTED.name === 'DirectionalLightHelper') {
            var object = scene.getObjectByName("DirectionalLight");
            object.color = new THREE.Color(e);
        }
    } );
});
```

The only problem is that, if I have 2 SpotLights/PointLight/DirectionalLights, it only works on the first one.

Comment: So how can you award yourself the correct answer for something that does not work?